gganimate in R: animating point 1 to split into point2a and point2b
In a dataset, observation 1 has one value in stage 1 and 2 values in stage 2. For instance, observation 1 is the median US income across all workers in stage 1 and the median US income across (a) women and (b) men in stage 2.
I want to animate the data point splitting into two data points.
Here are some data.
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

dat = tibble(
  id = 0,
  y = 0,
  a = 0,
  b = a - 2,
  c = a + 2
) |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(id,y)) |> 
  mutate(stage = ifelse(name == 'a', 'first', 'second'))

dat

# A tibble: 3 × 5
     id     y name  value stage 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1     0     0 a         0 first 
2     0     0 b        -2 second
3     0     0 c         2 second

All rows belong to observation 0. It has one value, 0, for the first stage, named "a". It has two values, -2 and +2, for the second stage, named "b" and "c", respectively.
The first plot looks like this.

p1 = dat[dat$stage == 'first',] |> 
  ggplot(aes(value,y)) +
  geom_point()


The second plot looks like this.

p1 = dat[dat$stage == 'second',] |> 
  ggplot(aes(value,y)) +
  geom_point()


I'd like to animate a transition using gganimate between p1 and p2, preserving the identity of the observation (this becomes relevant w/ multiple observations).

"preserving the identity of the observation" -- what do you mean by that? Simply identifying with colour or adding a label containing id?

Side note: We can do split(dat, ~stage) |> lapply(\(x) ggplot(x, aes(value, y)) + geom_point()), this prevents us from a lot of typing if there are many stages.

We could pad the data so that each stage gets the same number of observations per id as that id has in its most prevalent stage:
library(tidyverse); library(gganimate)
{dat |>
  mutate(obs_num = row_number(), .by = c(id, stage)) |>
  complete(stage, nesting(id, obs_num)) |>
  group_by(id) |> fill(y, value) |> ungroup() |>
  
  ggplot(aes(value, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_void() +
  transition_states(stage, state_length = 0) +
  ease_aes("cubic-in-out") } |>
  animate(fps = 25, height = 10)


